# Windows 10 change display language automatically after upgrade

Tags: windows-10, language

> OS Name:   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
>
> Version:   10.0.17134 Build 17134

Windows 10 always change my display language automatically  after upgrade.

I have three language packages install in my Windows, English, Chinese and Japanese.

The display language set by myself is English.

[image: image of language list]
[image: location image]

**But after every major version upgrade, it changes to Chinese.**

I thought the probable cause is that I have set my system `non-Unicode encoding` to `Chinese Simplified` to avoid some encoding bug.

How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Did the update always change the display language to the same language or random language? Is it the language you first install operation system on the machine?

Comment: @OOOO, always changes to Chinese Simplified. I thought the first language is not Chinese, but I'm not sure. My OS is upgraded from `Windows 7` which installed long long ago.